# Google plus share

Tags: google-plus

I use Muse and I want to be able to share the current URL dynamically. I have achieved this with Facebook and Twitter. However Google Plus is still evading me.

This is the JS code I have been working with.

```
<script language="javascript">
function gplussharecurrentpage() {
     sharelink = "https://plus.google.com/share?url={URL}"+url;
      newwindow=window.open(sharelink,'name','height=400,width=600');
      if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}                                                                                                                                
      return false;
    }   
   var url="www.google.co.uk";
        googleplusbtn(url);
</script>
```

I have a button linked to activate the script however it comes back with a this link is not valid.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you tried it without the {URL}? Try it

Comment: Yes,,, still says the link is not valid. What I want to do it to make it that I attach the JS to the master page and every page that I create from that has the correct JS to pull the link/description etc etc

Comment: I have managed to get it so that it at least shares the site but still not picking up the whole URL